# MongoDB shell command line authentication fails

Tags: mongodb, authentication, database-replication

I set up replica set with authentication. I used [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) tutorial. I set up keyfile, admin user and other users. It all works fine - anonymous access is disabled and I can login

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: not authorized on admin to execute     command { getLog: "startupWarnings" }
rs0:PRIMARY> use admin
switched to db admin
rs0:PRIMARY> db.auth("USERNAME","PASSWORD")
1
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

using credentials of users I created.

But I can't login from command line

```
$ mongo -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD'
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
2014-05-18T14:23:47.324+0200 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at   src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

using the same credentials. I haven't find anything helpful in the documentation or here on SO.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The in-shell authentication performed in your example is against the **admin** database. The command line posted above does not specify a database and is therefore authenticating against the default database which is **test**. Try this instead to authenticate via command line against the admin db:

```
mongo admin -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD'
```

if the server is not on the local host then you can use this:

```
mongo your_host_name:your_port/admin -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD'
```

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't figure that out... thanx, it works :-)

Comment: This question and answer deserves many upvotes because it is NOT specified properly in the Mongo docs.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: 

`mongo your_host_name:your_PORT/admin -u 'USERNAME' -p 'PASSWORD' `

Comment: Good catch @sebweisgerber - I will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps different now because of an update since this question was originally answered, but authentication only succeeds when wrapping username/password in double quotes.
e.g.,

```
mongo admin -u "myName" -p "myPassword"
```