# MongoDB - can't get data exported with mongoexport due to auth failed

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have a Mongo DB database and I trying to export couple "records" from one of the collections present in this database. Here is the command I am trying to use and the error I am getting:

```
mongoexport --collection my_collection --out my_collection.json --limit 10 --db my_db --username mongoadmin --password secret --host localhost

connected to: localhost
assertion: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }
```

Don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Try to use mongo admin command first.

Comment: just a guess, try: `--authenticationDatabase admin`, assuming user credentials (mongoadmin) are stored in `admin` database

Comment: To use mongo admin see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721866/mongodb-2-6-1-command-line-authentication-fails

Comment: It worked perfectly. I got a JSON file having 10 "records". To the command line I used I only added the parameter you suggested and everything worked perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Worked perfect with that additional parameter `--authenticationDatabase admin`.

Comment: Yup. Worked Smooth. Thanks

Comment: I have been trying to export data for like an hour, I can connect with mongosh but couldn't do anything with mongodump and mongoexport... Why that basic argument solved the problem? Why I can't just simply export data like I can connect to the database...

Answer (score 14):

Adding the additional parameter didn't work for me.

I contacted mLab support and was told the shell and/or driver I was connecting with was not compatible with MongoDB 3.0.x, the version that my database was running.

I installed 3.0.10 and was then able to connect successfully.

Comment: match the local mongod driver version with the server version. that's it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason no matter what i did, `mongoexport` or `mongodump` utilities didnt work for me as the default user, even after resetting my password, whilst I was, however, able to connect as default user to the mongo shell.

But the solution for me was from the settings page of your database on mlabs.com you can create more users, and i was then able to connect to these utilities with the new user. You can probably create new users in the shell too, but id just use the online tool.

```
mongoexport -h <serverURL:port> -d <database> -c <collection> -u <newuser> -p <newpassword> -o collection.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new user/password in mlabs.com settings worked for me.